# filling blank cells, merging duplicate values and sum up value based on another cell value macro

Tags: excel, vba, merge, sum

I am trying to create macro to fill blank cells with above values then merge the duplicate values and sum the unique values in column C basis on another cell value Column A & B.I have tried but it's not working as per expectation. It's getting messed up; unable to find out the reason.

Please help to understand the exact issue and way to correct it.

**Data**

[image: Data]

**Result**

[image: Result]

```
Sub merge()

Columns("A:C").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"

Dim i As Long
Dim lr As Long

Dim val As String
Dim total As Long
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
With ActiveSheet
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    val = .Cells(2, 1).Value & .Cells(2, 2).Value
    For i = 2 To lr
        total = .Cells(i, 3).Value
        If .Cells(i, 1).Value & .Cells(i, 2).Value <> val Then
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value = .Cells(i, 1).Offset(-1).MergeArea(1, 1).Value Then
                total = .Cells(i, 3).Offset(-1).MergeArea(1, 1) + .Cells(i, 3).Value
                .Range(.Cells(i, 3), .Cells(i, 3).Offset(-1)).merge
                .Cells(i, 3).MergeArea(1, 1).Value = total
                val = .Cells(i, 1).Value & .Cells(i, 2).Value
            Else
                val = .Cells(i, 1).Value & .Cells(i, 2).Value
            End If
        Else
            If Not i = 2 Then
                .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 1).Offset(-1)).merge
                .Range(.Cells(i, 2), .Cells(i, 2).Offset(-1)).merge
                .Range(.Cells(i, 3), .Cells(i, 3).Offset(-1)).merge
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: *getting messed up* is fairly useless information.  And why merged cells? They can be difficult to deal with.

Comment: merge is required to see how much value are been consumed under opportunity and by whom.. Sorry for the table.. I have amended it with correct values. logic is to obtain the sum of unique numbers (20+40=60)

Comment: I  would suggest having Opportunity and Value in a single cell; and have a concatenated (by linefeed) list of Name in the middle cell (a task easily accomplished with Power Query). I think it would display your results equally well, and avoid future potential difficulties with merged cells.

Comment: @ Ron.. thanks for help.. I have found the mistake.. Issue was with merging of cells which i corrected now.. thanks for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try with this. Just note it could fail if there are already merged cells within the range it's operating on. So be sure to save the file before testing.

```
Sub Merge()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim ws As Worksheet, lrow As Long, i As Long, StartRow As Long, _
SumCells As Double, StartName As Long, j As Long

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
lrow = ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
StartRow = 2
StartName = 2
SumCells = 0

With ws
    For i = 2 To lrow
        If .Range("B" & i) <> "" Or i = lrow Then
            If i > StartRow Then
                SumCells = SumCells + .Range("C" & i - 1)
                If i = lrow Then
                    j = i
                Else
                    j = i - 1
                End If
                .Range("B" & StartName, "B" & j).Merge
                .Range("A" & StartName, "A" & j).Merge
                StartNumber = .Range("A" & StartName)
                StartName = i
                If .Range("A" & i) <> "" Or i = lrow Then
                    .Range("C" & StartRow, "C" & j).Merge
                    .Range("C" & StartRow).Value = SumCells
                    StartRow = i
                    SumCells = 0
                Else
                    .Range("A" & i) = StartNumber
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    
    .Range("A2:C" & lrow).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Range("A2:C" & lrow).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: @ Simon thanks.. U r correct even my coding is also not working if cells are already merged...

Answer (score 0):

This is how to use user-defined functions.

```
Sub test()
    Dim rngDB As Range
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With
    
    Set rngDB = Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    On Error Resume Next
    
    'Fill the empty cells with the same values as above.
    rngDB.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Formula = "=r[-1]"
    
    'Set only the first column of data.
    Set rngDB = Range("a2", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    
    'Pass the first column of data and the number of the column to be added to the user-defined function as parameters.
    MergeRange rngDB, 3

     With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
 End Sub
 Sub MergeRange(rngDB As Range, c As Integer)
    'rngDB is first colum of data
    'c is colum of sum range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rngO As Range, myCell As Range
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    
    Set wf = WorksheetFunction
    
    For Each rng In rngDB
        If rng <> "" Then
            n = wf.CountIf(rngDB, rng)
            Set rngO = rng.Offset(, 1).Resize(n)
            MergeRange rngO, c
            For Each myCell In rngO
                If myCell <> "" Then
                    myCell.Resize(wf.CountIf(rngO, myCell)).Merge
                End If
            Next myCell
           If IsNumeric(rng) And rng.Column = c Then
                rng.Value = wf.Sum(rng.Resize(n))
            End If
            rng.Resize(n).Merge
        End If
    Next rng

End Sub
```

---

### If the value to be sum is in column 3

```
 MergeRange rngDB, 3
```

**data1**

[image]

**result1**

[image]

### If the value to be sum is in column 4

```
 MergeRange rngDB, 4
```

**data2**

[image]

**result2**

[image]

Comment: I see the OP has accepted your answer, but I should point out that your answer doesn't do what the OP has shown for their goal. Mainly you are summing up the values for each line rather than only summing the different ones. Just an FYI.

Comment: @ Simon i have found the mistake with my coding and corrected.. I have posted the changes which I made in my coding..

Answer (score 0):

thanks for support.. I have found the answer.. Issue was with Merging coding. I have made below changes and now it's working fine.

```
With Range("A2:C" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row)
 .SpecialCells(xlBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
.Value = .Value
End With
```